# How to get SVN's revert behaviour in Git

Tags: git, svn

I know, I know, `git revert` but I just learned that it does not behave exactly the same as `svn revert`--at least, not in Visual Studio 2015, or maybe not in TortoiseGit.  I'll explain:

I am new to VS2015 also new to Git.  When I discovered that VS2015 has Git integration right out of the box, I tried it out.  However, I was working on several files and I was ready to commit just one of them.  Unfortunately, the filter that I applied in the Team Explorer pane did not apply to which files were committed (I guess that's why the button's title is "Commit All").  Instead, it committed all "dirty" files--oops!

Resorting to TortoiseGit to view my repo's log, I selected the most recent (local) commit and reverted it via "Revert changes by this commit".  I had expected that this operation would revert the files that I was working on to back to the "dirty" state they were in before I had committed, like what an SVN Revert does, but to my surprise, the operation reverted my local files to the previous *repo* version, not to the state they were in before I had committed them.

Of course, I was able to retrieve my work because it was all in the "all files" revision that I had originally committed.  I just set to work on copying each file from it to its rightful directory.  But what am I missing here?  Is there a Git feature that I should have used instead of Revert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Git, you can remove an entire commit. Preferably you’d only do this to commits that are not pushed. The whole “distributed” part of Git makes that possible. With SVN, your changes are immediately available for others. With Git they are only available once they are pushed (“Sync” in Visual Studio).

So, instead of reverting the commit (which means the erroneous changes would remain in the repository and can have unexpected side effects), do `git reset --mixed HEAD~1`. This means your working directory will stay as is, but the last commit will be removed. That means Git will show all the files as modified again.

Reverting in Git creates an “inverse” commit of the commit you reverted, undoing all changes.

Then, to commit only a single file, first check with `git status` that Git does not have unwanted changes staged. Then, use `git add path/to/file.txt` to stage (only) that file. After that, just execute `git commit`, use an appropriate commit message and you’re done.

When you run `git commit` and the text editor pops up, the file also contains a list of changes that will be committed. Carefully inspect this list to make sure you only commit what you want.

Also, do not use Visual Studio to actively work with Git. It tries to apply legacy TFS terms to Git operations, but they aren’t the same. Instead, try to learn Git on the console. Visual Studio has some nice perks for read-only work, like a great diff view.

Comment: `--mixed` is the default, and the list of changes is (AFAIK) a relatively new thing – it used to require `git commit -v` previously, didn't it?

Comment: @grawity Yes, `--mixed` is the default. I added if for clarification. The list of changes (well, changed files, really) has “always” been there IIRC. I don’t have an older Git installation to verify it, though.